# why truncated param in this Linux kernel code?

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I am confused  by the code in kernel/sched/sched.h in Linux kernel.
Like the newest version code in kernel.org.
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/sched/sched.h?h=v5.3-rc4
Line 285-299.

```
__dl_update(dl_b, (s32)tsk_bw / cpus);
```

The function "__dl_update" need s64 type in second arg.
The tsk_bw is u64 type.
Why  use "s32", not "s64"???

```
static inline void __dl_update(struct dl_bw *dl_b, s64 bw);

static inline
void __dl_sub(struct dl_bw *dl_b, u64 tsk_bw, int cpus)
{
    dl_b->total_bw -= tsk_bw;
    __dl_update(dl_b, (s32)tsk_bw / cpus);
}

static inline
void __dl_add(struct dl_bw *dl_b, u64 tsk_bw, int cpus)
{
    dl_b->total_bw += tsk_bw;
    __dl_update(dl_b, -((s32)tsk_bw / cpus));
}

static inline
bool __dl_overflow(struct dl_bw *dl_b, int cpus, u64 old_bw, u64 new_bw)
{
    return dl_b->bw != -1 &&
           dl_b->bw * cpus < dl_b->total_bw - old_bw + new_bw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One reason may be that a 32-bit signed division takes 26 cycles, whereas 64-bit one takes 42-95 cycles on Skylake. 64-bit signed division is the most expensive division, so it makes sense to avoid it as much as possible. See [Agner Fog's Instruction tables](https://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf).

Comment: I think safety should be more important, isn't it?

Comment: @liu To answer that, one would need to know the what `tsk_bw` and `bw` are and their valid ranges.